# about complement of a graph

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a $k-$regular graph on $n$ vertices. we know that if $k\geq n/2$, then $G$ is a connected graph. Now, if we take complement of graph $G$ and denote it as $\bar G$ then $\bar G$ will be $(n-k-1)-$ regular graph and if  $(n-k-1)\geq n/2$ then $\bar G$ will be a connected graph. I Want to gain some extra knowledge about the complement of such $k-$regular graphs. It is clear that if $(n-k-1)< n/2$ then we can not say anything about the connectivity of the graph $\bar G$. I tried numerically few examples from the page http://www.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/markus/reggraphs.html.

Is there any condition that we assume such that complement of $k$ regular graph is a disconnected graph. Any help or hint will be helpful to me. Thanks for paying attention.

Comment: What sort of condition are you looking for? Clearly if $k=n$ or $k=n-1$ the complement will be disconnected, for any other $k$ we can find examples that make the complement connected.

Comment: @Gamamal . Any condition on minimum degree of the graph or regularity?

Comment: any condition on the graph $G$ such that its complement is disconnected graph. most obvious is the complete graph. but other than that?

Comment: As @Gamamal stated, if $G$ is $n-1$-regular, then the complement is 0-regular, and therefore disconnected if $G$ is non-trivial (more than one vertex). Similarly, if $G$ is $n-2$-regular, then the complement is 1-regular, and as long as there are at least 3 vertices, that's also disconnected.

Comment: @WilliamMacrae 1 regular? is there any such graph. there is only one graph $K_2$.

Comment: There are also graphs made up of the union of $K_2$s, such as $(\{a,b,c,d\},\{ab,cd\})$.